# Updated PostgreSQL client connectivity for Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, delphi-xe2

I'm looking for updated connectivity options to connect with PostgreSQL with Delphi XE2. What are you currently utilizing to connect with PostgreSQL and Delphi XE2?  (Does it work with 32 and 64-bit applications?)

Comment: I'd like to know if anyone's doing anything for PostgreSQL connectivity on the Mac.  Both MicroOlap and DevArt's components have been updated for 64-bit Windows, but nobody's talking Mac yet.  I don't have XE2 yet, but right now (XE) I'm using dbGo -> ODBC -> psqlodbc, and I'd expect to continue with that or dbExpress/ODBC -> psqlodbc, since PostgreSQL has both 32 & 64 bit ODBC drivers.

Comment: Looks like I spoke a bit too soon: Devart's VCL Data Access Components seem to have Mac & FreePascal/Lazarus support now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevArt is the way to go. http://www.devart.com/pgdac/. They released 64-bit support for XE2 in September and announced iOS support in XE2 last week.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if their unidac product has all the Postgres features available of their pgdac product?

Comment: @Darian- depends on what you mean by "all the Postgres features". I haven't used their Unidac product. You can download a free 60-day trial version and check it out for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I use [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) - not only for PostgreSQL, highly recommend it !

Comment: Have you compared it to DevArt's pgdac?  Does AnyDAC have features that you use which pgdac doesn't offer?

Comment: No, I only compared AnyDAC to UniDAC, because I need universal data access library. AnyDAC offers more features than UniDAC:
Data Type Unification - same data type mapping for different DBMS’s, automatically recognizes auto-incrementing data type, SQL script processor support different SQL script dialects, very fast Array DML to insert, update, delete many records, ...